# Building this implementation of IWebHostBuilder is not supported in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

I am trying upgrade my .net core 2.2 to 3.1 and getting following error.

> Building this implementation of IWebHostBuilder is not supported.

> EndpointRoutingMiddleware matches endpoints setup by EndpointMiddleware and so must be added to the request execution pipeline before EndpointMiddleware.
> Please add EndpointRoutingMiddleware by calling 'IApplicationBuilder.UseRouting' inside the call to 'Configure(...)' in the application startup code.

I am not sure why this is complaining about `IWebHostBuilder`.

Can someone please guide me.

Program.cs

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                     IHost webHost = (IHost)BuildWebHost(args);
                      var runTask = webHost.RunAsync();
                            runTask.Wait();
                            return;          
                }
         
                     
public static IHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
                        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults
                        (Web =>
                        {
                            Web.UseStartup<Startup>()
                              .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
                              .UseSerilog()
                              .Build();
                        });
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");               
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpContext();
          
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                        endpoints.MapControllers());           
        }
```

Comment: Delete the code `.Build();`

Comment: @Yinqiu, When I removed `Build()`, it's complaining about `Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHost'.`. Can you please help me to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: Try this `public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run();
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
//...

   (Web =>
    {
        Web.UseStartup<Startup>()
          .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
          .UseSerilog()
          .Build(); //<--DON'T DO THIS
    });
```

is causing the original problem because of

```
//...GenericWebHostBuilder

public IWebHost Build()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException($"Building this implementation of {nameof(IWebHostBuilder)} is not supported.");
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/GenericHost/GenericWebHostBuilder.cs#L171)

The code needs to be refactored to

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
     IHost host = BuildWebHost(args);
     await host.RunAsync();  
}
                 
public static IHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(Web => {
            Web.UseStartup<Startup>()
              .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
              .UseSerilog();
        })
        .Build();
```

In order to follow the suggested format from documentation.

If there is no need for the code to be async then this will work as well

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    IHost host = BuildWebHost(args);
    host.Run();  
}
```

Comment: Sorry for keep modifying the question. When I changed accordingly. Now I am getting another issue from `Startup.cs`. Here is issue `EndpointRoutingMiddleware matches endpoints setup by EndpointMiddleware and so must be added to the request execution pipeline before EndpointMiddleware. 
Please add EndpointRoutingMiddleware by calling 'IApplicationBuilder.UseRouting' inside the call to 'Configure(...)' in the application startup code.`

Comment: @user10216769 the instruction in that exception are very clear. Just do what it is instructing you to do.

Comment: @user10216769 I would also suggest reviewing the migration documentation since a lot has changed from the version you are migrating from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio